# Can Protractor test an Angular application which has debugInfoEnabled disabled?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I wanted to optimize our Angular application by utilizing the 1.3 version [recommended](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data) `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);`

When that setting is turned on, Protractor tests stops working since Protractor seems to rely on some of that information for Angular related finders.
What would be the correct way to allow E2E testing with Protractor when your Angular debug information is turned off?

Answer (score 1):

@christianrondeau suggested in the Protractor [GitHub forums](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2116) to do:

```
onPrepare: function () {
  browser.executeScript('window.name = "NG_ENABLE_DEBUG_INFO"');
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to use the Angular provided `angular.reloadWithDebugInfo();` call?

Comment: I could not find a better solution; for Protractor to "connect" to AngularJS, debug has to be enabled, and onPrepare is called *before* your AngularJS app has been loaded, so it's a chicken and egg situation.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended answer did not work for me.  If it matters, we are running an Angular/AngularJS hybrid application, but I think more importantly our login page is not written in AngularJS so I'm pretty sure that using the `onPrepare` solution won't work since AngularJS is loaded after the initial phase of the tests.

What did work however is the solution mentioned at the bottom of that Github issue page, and that was to use `browser.executeScript('angular.reloadWithDebugInfo()');`.  I have this call happening at the end of our login page and after we've tested for Angular elements to be present on the page using basic element selectors.